# Teradata merge multiple records into single record

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to merge multiple record into single record
Ex:
Input

| pdt | status | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Inactive | 2022/02/02 | 2022/02/04 |
| a | Inctive | 2022/02/05 | 2022/02/10 |
| a | Active | 2022/02/10 | 2022/02/12 |
| b | Active | 2022/03/13 | 2022/03/17 |

Output

| pdt | status | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Active | 2022/02/02 | 2022/02/12 |
| b | Active | 2022/03/13 | 2022/03/17 |

Comment: Teradata's `SELECT NORMALIZE` does this. It requires a PERIOD data type, but you can use the PERIOD constructor, normalize, then use BEGIN and END functions to extract individual dates. Also note PERIOD is up to but not including the ending value so `BETWEEN date'2022-03-03' AND date'2022-03-17'` corresponds to `PERIOD(date'2022-03-03',date'2022-03-18')` and so on. The NEXT and PRIOR functions provide a general way to adjust the period end.

Comment: @Fred I have edited my question. I am not able to achieve the latest status using normalize option. Could you pleasee help me

Comment: What are your rules for combining those rows? Do you just want one row per pdt with the latest status, or multiple rows if there are gaps (and how do you define a gap)?

Comment: @dnoeth yes multiple rows if there are gaps... if no gap then 1 record with latest status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize the date ranges first, then join back to pick up the most recent status.

```
SELECT t1.pdt, t2.status, BEGIN(t1.pd) as start_dt, PRIOR(END(t1.pd)) AS end_dt
FROM (
  SELECT NORMALIZE pdt, PERIOD(start_dt, NEXT(end_dt)) pd 
  FROM mytable ) as t1
JOIN mytable t2
ON t1.pdt = t2.pdt AND PRIOR(END(t1.pd)) = t2.end_dt;
```

Comment: Any idea how to implement this in biquery?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming start_dt and end_dt are both DATE types:

```
select pdt, status, min(start_dt), max(end_dt) from your_table
where to_char(start_dt,'YYYY/MM')=to_char(end_dt,'YYYY/MM')
group by pdt, status, to_char(start_dt,'YYYY/MM')
```